# UIVisualEffectView stack overflow accessing contentView

Tags: ios

I'm developing an iOS app (the original code is not mine). The code below works fine in iOS 9/10 but on iOS 11 it enters an infinite loop of calling 
`addSubview`.

```
import UIKit

class BlurView: UIVisualEffectView {

    var isRounded: Bool

    init(style: UIBlurEffectStyle, isRounded: Bool = true) {
        self.isRounded = isRounded

        super.init(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))

        setupInterface()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        guard view !== contentView else {
            super.addSubview(view)
            return
        }

        contentView.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

If I substitute the effect parameter in the line `super.init(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))` for `nil` it works fine (of course, without the blur).

Additional information: inside the addSubView I can't access the `contentView` property, which seems to be the one that creates the stack overflow problem. On the init it looks like it's internally used, and  that's where it breaks.

The questions are: 
Why does this work on iOS 9/10 and not iOS 11?
How can I make this work on iOS 11?